# How to write sql query with if statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables question and answer. Question have few answers. Depends on "allow_multi_select" flag in question we can chose one or few answers for question.

Answer have "preferred" flag.

Now I wanna count questions that allows multi select answers and all of selected answers are preferred.

For example if question have three answers and two of them are preferred I wanna count this question only if this two are selected.

How to write query like this?

EDIT:

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_question (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  sid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  question VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
  text_answer BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  multi_answers BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  "index" int4 NOT NULL,
  survey_sid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  text_answer_value TEXT,
  survey_definition_question_sid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  preferred_answers BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  survey_definition_sid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE survey_answer (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  sid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  answer VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  "index" int4 NOT NULL,
  preferred BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  survey_question_sid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  survey_definition_answer_sid VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE survey_question_answer_relation (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  survey_question_id int8 NOT NULL,
  survey_answer_id int8 NOT NULL,
);
```

I didn't post schema first time couse is litte more complitcated.

Comment: Post the tables schemas. `\d question` `\d answer`

Comment: +1 for keeping to set based logic instead of going straight to procedural.  Just update your question to have the table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Given this schema

```
create table question (
    question_id int,
    allow_multi_select boolean
);

create table answer (
    answer_id int,
    question_id int,
    preferred boolean,
    selected boolean
);
```

created in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/775e9/2),

```
select count(*) as total
from (
    select question_id
    from
        question q
        inner join
        answer a using (question_id)
    where allow_multi_select and preferred
    group by question_id
    having bool_and(selected)
) s
```

Comment: This solution count question also if not preferred answer and preferred are selected. I wanna count only if all preferred answers are selected.

Comment: @MrJedi So where is your schema and sample data?

Comment: I edited question. Question and answer are connected by relation in my real case.